# Does get{} and set{} only for computed properties?

Tags: swift

I have a question about property in Swift.
Does get{} and set{} only support the computed properties?

```
var name: String {

  get {
     // return something
  }

  set {
    //  do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question no verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is still unclear (even though you added the missing verb).  Nevertheless I'll try to answer it:

1. Only computed properties may have `get` and `set` blocks.  That is what makes them “computed”.
2. The opposite of a computed property is a “stored” property. (The language reference calls this a “stored variable property”.) A stored property cannot have `get` and `set` blocks.
3. You can observe changes to stored properties, and to inherited properties of any kind, by defining `willSet` and `didSet` blocks for them.

Many details are spelled out in [“Properties” in *The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_380).  You can also search for “Properties” in the [“Declarations” section of language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_543).  (Interior links into the language reference don't work as of this writing.)